# PropertyGrid Not Updating List of String

Tags: .net, vb.net, properties, propertygrid

I'm having a little trouble with a `PropertyGrid`.

I have set the selected object to a class containing various properties and 90% of them work correctly but for any where the property is a `List(Of String)` it doesn't appear to call the `Set` part of the property.

The class I have is as follows (shortened version):

```
Public Class VideosProperties
    Public Property EpisodeColorOdd As Color
        Get
            Return Videos_EpisodeColorOdd
        End Get
        Set(value As Color)
            Videos_EpisodeColorOdd = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
    "System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor,System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")>
    Public Property Extensions As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return Videos_Extensions
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of String))
            Videos_Extensions = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I have set the `SelectedObject` to be this class using the following code:

```
Dim _Properties As Object

_Properties = New VideosProperties

PropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = _Properties
```

I have Initialized the List using the following code:

```
Extensions = New List(Of String)
```

When I run my code, the `PropertyGrid` shows the `EpisodeColorOdd` property and this works correctly, but the Extensions property doesn't.

When you edit the Extensions property using the `PropertyGrid`, it doesn't call the `Set(value as List(Of String))` part of the property.

I've had a look around and can't seem to find a solution (I'm probably not looking hard enough).

Can anyone help?

**EDIT**

Plutonix - Your code doesn't work.  I have already copied and pasted into a new project and I get errors.
I get an error at

```
<Editor("System.Windows.Forms...etc")>
```

telling me "Type 'Editor' is not defined", so I Imported "System.ComponentModel" and now get 
an error saying "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments." at the same point.

If I remove the that part it doesn't work correctly.

I run the code, the form opens, I click on the Foods property and an Editor opens, I click Add and get the error "Constructor on type 'System.String' not found." which I've had before, 
and I fixed using

```
<Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", "System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor,System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")>
```

instead of

```
<Editor("System.Windows.Forms...etc")>
```

Now though, when I click on the property, it brings up a different editor and doesn't actually access the Set part of the property. So, I'm back to square one.

Comment: a) `"...etc"` was clearly shorthand for the long editor designation, sorry. b) there is no context for where or when the Extension list is instantiated. c) `doesn't actually access the Set part of the property` and it never will and isnt supposed to.  Re-read the answer.  Collection Editors edit the items in the collection, *not* the collection object

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood your post.  I've just checked, and it updates the List in the `Get` section of the code.  The reason why it was an issue, is because on the `Set` part for all the other properties I was calling some code to update my registry.  Since it wasn't using `Set` it wasn't updating and it was basically not saving my settings.  I've now added this code into the `Get` area and it's working correctly. Thanks for the help, Plutonix, it's much appreciated. :-)

Comment: [This link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718006/Enhanced-CollectionEditor-Framework) explains more how collection editors work.  If you have to qualify/process each item, use a list the generates events or write a Collection Class.  When the editor invokes the `.Add` or `.AddRange` method, you can have code validate the item or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant be sure but from the code shown, you dont initialize the collection.  Both the `PropertyGrid` and `StringCollectionEditor` are intended to edit *existing* properties values. By not initializing the `List` - which itself is an object - that property container does not exist and neither of them will create it for you.

Your code shows the getter/setter boilerplate, but nothing about the backing fields.

Also, since `VideosProperties` is a Type, you should use it to declare your variable as that Type rather than `As Object`.  By doing that, you are casting the var to the lowest possible form; your properties are only available via late binding which requires `Option Strict` off.

```
Public Class Animal
    ' auto implement props available since VS2010:
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Species As String
    Public Property Weight As Double
    Public Property Coloring As Color

    ' backing field for the List:
    Private mFoods As List(Of String)

    ' this of course would be the same as your code...
    ' no need to repeat
    <Editor("System.Windows.Forms...etc")>
    Public Property Foods As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return mFoods
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of String))
            ' see notes
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(n As String, s As String)
        Name = n
        Species = s
        ' initialize the List instance:
        mFoods = New List(Of String)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The key is that in the constructor (`Sub New`) you create the list instance to hold the food items, video extensions or whatever.  Using it:

```
' class/form level variable declared as Animal NOT Object
Private A As Animal
...
A = New Animal("Ziggy", "Feline")
A.Weight = 12.4             ' not possible if A is As Object

pGrid.SelectedObject = A
```

After the edit, `A.Foods` will contain whatever was entered via the `StringCollectionEditor`.  If `A` is declared `As Object`, the code line to set the `Weight` will prevent the code from compiling (with `Option Strict` on).  This is because `System.Object` does not have a `Weight` property.  `A As Animal` allows the compiler to see and use the properties defined.  I suspect you are not using `Option Strict`.

**If** your object has a valid `List` instance when you send your object to the `PropertyGrid` *and* a valid Editor is specified, you'll see this:

[image]

The PropGrid will display "Collection" indicating it knows what it is, and the "..." indicates the PropGrid has a valid editor associated with it.  Proof that it retains the collection:

```
lbFoods.Items.AddRange(A.Foods.ToArray)
' results in:
```

[image][image]

---

Note that I have nothing in the setter for `Foods`, yet it works.  Collection Editors do not usually pass collection items back *en masse* via the setter. Instead, they use the `Add` and/or `AddRange` method of the collection.

So, I can omit the setter which also prevents some piece of code from setting the `List` back to `Nothing`.  Of course, code can change the string items to something else or re order them which also might be bad.

To avoid this, you might want to use a Collection Class which implements `List(of T)` or `Collection(Of T)`.  This way your code can provide access to items, limit what can be done, and even validate items added.

See [Guidelines for Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389(v=vs.110).aspx) for more tips and information.